# Cannot use Mahapps in plugin project

Tags: c#, wpf, xamarin, mvvmcross, mahapps.metro

I am developing wpf application with MvvmCross. I have my own dialog plugin that has a alert window. It will pop up when I click on some buttons to confirm my action. Previously, alert window is just a simple wpf window. But I want to use Mahapps to style it.

The problem is when I changed the base class of AlertWindow from window to Mahapps's MetroWindow an error has occurred "Could not find plugin type in assembly"

Below is my code in xaml file and c# file

```
<Controls:MetroWindow x:Class="Test.MvvmCross.Plugins.Dialog.Wpf.AlertWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
        Title="" Height="120" Width="350" SizeToContent="Height" ShowInTaskbar="False" ResizeMode="NoResize" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" >
    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Test.MvvmCross.Plugins.Dialog.Wpf;component/Styles/Generic.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>

    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="10" Text="{Binding Message}" Name="MessageTb">asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfa asdfas asdf asdf asdf</TextBlock>
        <DockPanel Margin="5" Background="White">
            <Button DockPanel.Dock="Right" Margin="5" Height="30" Width="65" Name="NeutralButton" IsCancel="True">
                <Grid>
                    <ContentControl Style="{StaticResource Content1NormalButtonStyle}" >
                        <TextBlock Name="NeutralContent1Textblock" Foreground="{StaticResource ButtonNotSelectedColorBrush}"/>
                    </ContentControl>
                    <ContentControl Style="{StaticResource Content2NormalButtonStyle}" >
                        <TextBlock Name="NeutralContent2Textblock" Foreground="{StaticResource ButtonTextColorBrush}" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                    </ContentControl>
                </Grid>
            </Button>
            <Button DockPanel.Dock="Right" Margin="5" Height="30" Width="65" Name="NegativeButton">
                <Grid>
                    <ContentControl Style="{StaticResource Content1NormalButtonStyle}" >
                        <TextBlock Name="NegativeContent1Textblock" Foreground="{StaticResource ButtonNotSelectedColorBrush}"/>
                    </ContentControl>
                    <ContentControl Style="{StaticResource Content2NormalButtonStyle}" >
                        <TextBlock Name="NegativeContent2Textblock" Foreground="{StaticResource ButtonTextColorBrush}" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                    </ContentControl>
                </Grid>
            </Button>
            <Button DockPanel.Dock="Right"  Margin="5" Height="30" Width="65" Name="PositiveButton" IsDefault="True" >
                <Grid>
                    <ContentControl Style="{StaticResource Content1NormalButtonStyle}" >
                        <TextBlock Name="PositiveContent1Textblock" Foreground="{StaticResource ButtonNotSelectedColorBrush}"/>
                    </ContentControl>
                    <ContentControl Name="PositiveContent2" Style="{StaticResource Content2NormalButtonStyle}" >
                        <TextBlock Name="PositiveContent2Textblock" Foreground="{StaticResource ButtonTextColorBrush}" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                    </ContentControl>
                </Grid>
            </Button>
            <Control />
        </DockPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</Controls:MetroWindow>
```

This is the and error message [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTDXb.png).

**I have updated the xaml code

I have used Mahapps in my main project with no problem. Please let me know if you not understand what i want or anything else.

Comment: Can you post the exact error message?

Comment: Where does you include the `Style` resources.

Comment: @Matthew I am not sure about your question. I add it in the <Window.Resource>

Comment: The message "Could not find plugin type in assembly" suggests the reflection to find the Plugin.cs class is failing - debug that area - not the xaml - that's my guess

Comment: @Stuart Could you please explain me more about this? I added the pinpoint too that class but it doesn't go there.

Comment: There's a wiki article about how plugins are loaded - that may help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution of my problem. It is the version of MahApps. Because the ui project use an older version than the plugin project.

After I changed them to be same, everything is fine.